# Trigger a click event on donut segment in morris.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I am able to keep a default segment in donut using Morris.select().

Apart from this I want to trigger a click event on the same (segment of default selection).
Is there a way to attain this?

I even tried `$('path').eq(1).trigger('click')`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to trigger a click?

Comment: I am showing a corresponding data in a div. I am generating chart for few data sets. on selection of each dataset, I want to represent data in div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `on('click')` function in your Morris Donut object. Then you can access the Donut data with the `row` parameter.

As you said, you can select a segment with the `select(index)` method of the Donut. Then if you want to display the data of the corresponding segment, call a function that takes the Donut data as parameter, ex: `morrisDonut.data[index]`.

Here is a working example:

```js
var morrisDonut = Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ],
  resize: true
}).on('click', function (i, row) {  
    // Do your actions
    // Example:
    displayData(i, row);
});

// Index of element to select
var i = 2;
// Selects the element in the Donut
morrisDonut.select(i);
// Display the corresponding data
displayData(i, morrisDonut.data[i]);

function displayData(i, row) {
    $('#data').html(row.label + ": " + row.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="donut"></div>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.. I found one more way.... as morris gives HIGH value Highlighted by default, I took  high value data from json initially..and then anyway on click of segment they show thier corresponding value.  Anyway Thanks ... This is quite easy than mine